# Cannot plot Nan (a Thailand province) in Excel map chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

I obtained Thailand province names and data [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_of_Thailand). I tried to plot the data using Excel, but one of the provinces is missing (see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA4NX.png)). It is *Nan*.

But when I changed the name to Thai (i.e., from *Nan* to *น่าน*), the data appeared.

How can I plot the data of the province?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After I change the cell to Geography (Data > Data Types > Geography).  I tried some formulas.  The formula *cell*`.[Admin Division 1 (State/province/other)]` works.  The name that can be plot on the map is *Nan Province*.

Comment: But why? What was the reason? Was Nan interpreted as ["not a number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (*NaN* - note the difference in capitalisation)?